# Hibernate Criteria in DB2

Tags: hibernate, db2

How to write Hibernate Criteria query to sort in descending order for first 10 rows only in DB2 dailect.

in Db2: I have employee table 20 records say starts from 1...20.

if i run below Query :

```
Select empname from emp order by desc empno fetch first 10 rows only.
```

Actual Output should be: 10,9....,1. But in DB2 it retunrs 20,19....11.

Any suggestions most appreciated.

Regards,

Raj

Comment: How is DB2 relevant to the question?

Comment: @Skaffman: Yes it is related to Db2 database.

Comment: The query does exactly what you are asking it to in DB2: you are asking it to order the employees by empno and then select the first 10 which would be 20, 19...11. What is your questions exactly? Do you want a query that returns 10,9,...1? Did you need to convert it into a Hibernate Criteria query?

Comment: @tkeE2036:I want a hibernate criteria query which returns first 10 rows in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can create a hibernate criteria query which returns the first 10 rows in descending order:

```
Critieria crit = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
crit.addOrder(Order.desc("empno");
crit.setMaxResults(10);
List<Employee> emps = crit.list();
```

Keep in mind that this will return the employees in descending order based on `empno` so it returning a result set of empno's like 20,19,...11. This is what its supposed to do, regardless of the underlying database, and as far as I can tell its what you asked for.

Let me know if you actually wanted it to be 10,9,...1 (which is technically not the first 10 rows in descending order).

**Edit:**
If you want it to be 10,9,...1 I would personally just change the criteria to sort in ascending order. The order will be 1...,9,10 but the effect is the same:

```
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("empno"));
```

If you really want it to be 10,9,...1 you can add the do the following though it becomes more dependent on the data you have. It all depends on what you are trying to do with the data but these should get you on the right path.

```
Critieria crit = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
crit.addOrder(Order.desc("empno");
crit.setFirstResult(10);
crit.setMaxResults(10);
List<Employee> emps = crit.list();
```

Comment: Thanks.I want this 10,9,...1 this order.

Comment: I have 20 records,Initially it displays 1...10 records.so if i do sorting it will display 10....1.Second:if i click next button criteria will displays 11 ...20.Here I want to sort to display 20....11.How above code will change,based on this scenario.